# How to monitor Firestore rules errors?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I just found out that 10% of my Firestore requests go in error:

[image]

These are my rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /notifications/{notification} {
      allow read, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.authUID;
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.authUID;
    }
    match /various/{doc} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I monitor which are these errors?
Or can you see anything particularly wrong in the rules definitions, which can cause errors?

**UPDATE**:
I have modified the rules according to what @Mises said, but I still get the errors:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /notifications/{notification} {
      allow read, delete, update: if request.auth != null && resource.data != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.authUID;
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.authUID;
    }
    match /various/{doc} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone can update every notification according to your rules.

Comment: Errors might be because of you not check are requests got auth.

Comment: @Mises thanks! do you mean, I should write:
`allow read, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.authUID;
allow create, update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.authUID;`

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure, but this might cause errors. Someone who is not logged in trying to get data.

Comment: And separate create with update. If user know doc IDs he can update them all. Update should have just resource, not request.resource. Like: `allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.authUID`.

Comment: I have tried, but I still get the errors. I even moved "update" together with "read" and "delete". You can see my update on the question.

Comment: Maybe setup rule on top like `match /{document=**} { allow read, write: if false; }` If this not help, I have no idea why you get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase console only provides an at-a-glance view of rules invocations. Is not possible to get error logs about specific parts of your security rules that fail.

You could enable and disable rules at a time to test which one is producing errors using one of these tools:

- [Rules playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) in the Firebase console.
- [Emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup) and its debug function.

Comment: Was this answer helpful?